# need to add only parent class objects in the list and restrict the sub class objects

Tags: java

i need to declare a list which should accept only the parent class objects and it should not allow the sub class objects.

```
parent class:

public class ParentClass {

  private String parentAttr;

  public String getParentAttr() {
    return parentAttr;
  }

  public void setParentAttr(String parentAttr) {
    this.parentAttr = parentAttr;
  }

}


Sub class:

public class SubClass1 extends ParentClass {

  private String attr1;

  public String getAttr1() {
    return attr1;
  }

  public void setAttr1(String attr1) {
    this.attr1 = attr1;
  }

}

Main class:

public class MainClass {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ParentClass parentClass=new ParentClass();

    SubClass1 subClass1 = new SubClass1();

    List<ParentClass> list=new ArrayList<ParentClass>(); // modify this declaration such that it should accept only the parent class objs

    list.add(parentClass);

    list.add(subClass1); // this should not happen. only parent class objects should be added in the list

  }

}
```

I tried using generics as well. but it is not working. is there any way to achieve this in java generics?

Comment: unfortunately `SubClass1` **IS A** `ParentClass` because it extends `ParentClass` class: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_inheritance.htm

Comment: The only possible solution i could think of is to declare the class as immutable which would be non extendable. Otherwise you are not able to do so purely with the standard implementation of the list.

Comment: Question really why would you want this.Why would a collection be concerned about this ?

Comment: @Shahzeb. this was the question asked in an interview. so i asked it

Answer (score 1):

You can Implement the [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interface and provide your own implementation for the [List.add(int index, E element)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28int,%20E%29) method and check if the element is instanceof the parent Class and not an instanceof the child Class in your implementation.

You can also extend the [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) Class and Override all the methods that add elements to the ArrayList and check if the element is instanceof the parent Class and not an instanceof the child Class in your implementation and call the Super method for process of adding the element(s).

Comment: `List<ParentClass> list=new ArrayList<ParentClass>(); // modify this declaration such that it should accept only the parent class objs
`  OP do not have a chance here to implement a new list. :)

Comment: He can extend the ArrayList Class, which I think is the easiest and safest approach.

Answer (score 0):

No. You just can't stop it. We can use every Child as a Parent. Every Child extends Parent and apparently it's a Parent as well.

Comment: hi, this was the question asked in an interview. so i tried it

Comment: @pradeep Interviewr might expected the answer that `every Child is a Parent, so we can't`.